# Installing GeoServer Cluster

Tags: geoserver

I try to deploy GeoServer cluster with GeoServer version 2.16.x.

I try to deploy my cluster in Ubuntu 16.04.

I have 2 VM machine with IP

- IP1: 203.162.141.7
- IP2: 203.162.141.13

Here is my install step (I perform the following steps on both machines)

1. Install default-jre and default-jdk
2. I dowload Geoserver package "Platform Independent Binary" by

   ```
   wget https://nchc.dl.sourceforge.net/project/geoserver/GeoServer/2.16.0/geoserver-2.16.0-bin.zip
   ```

   Then I unzip this file geoserver-2.16.0-bin.zip, put it in this path

   ```
   /usr/share/geoserver/geoserver-2.16.0/
   ```
3. Then I download 2 file:

   ```
   geoserver-2.16-SNAPSHOT-activeMQ-broker-plugin.zip
   geoserver-2.16-SNAPSHOT-jms-cluster-plugin.zip
   ```

Unzip anh put it in this path

```
    /usr/share/geoserver/geoserver-2.16.0/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib
```

4. Start geoserver

```
root@ubuntu16:~# echo "export GEOSERVER_HOME=/usr/share/geoserver/geoserver-2.16.0" >> ~/.profile
root@ubuntu16:~# . ~/.profile
root@ubuntu16:/usr/share/geoserver/geoserver-2.16.0# cd bin/
root@ubuntu16:/usr/share/geoserver/geoserver-2.16.0/bin# sh startup.sh
```

Result:

Geoserver start like this:

[image]

when I started two machines simultaneously, it show that error:

```
18 Nov 23:37:18 WARN [network.DiscoveryNetworkConnector] - Could not start network bridge between: vm://4e2acd70-0c58-4ca5-a91e-02ae8a6730ad?async=false&network=true and: nio://localhost:36433 due to: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

I don't know how to fix this and my install step to deploy cluster is correctly or not?

Comment: Running into this same issue now - were you able to resolve this?

Comment: yes, I have resolved it. Give me your email, I will send you my doc.